# Handling revisions - setting attributes or mutators for relation columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Pseudo code - say I have the models `Author`, `Document`, `Revisions`, `Editor`.

`Author` *hasMany* `Document`
`Document` *hasMany* `Revisions`
`Document` *hasMany* `Editors` (which are stored in the revision table)

But the following table structure:

*Author Model*: `id`, `name`, `email`
*Document Model*: `id`, `author_id`, `title`
*Revisions Model*: `id`, `document_id`, `editor_id`, `text`, `saved_at`
*Editor Model*: `id`, `name`, `email`

First question - to store the revision history (including which editor changed the text at which time); is this an ideal structure? I want to be able to do `$author->documents->where('title', 'Some title')->editor->name`;

To access the `Editor` from the `Document` - is it worth setting attributes directly in the `Document` constructor:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [] ){
  $this->setRawAttributes(
    array_merge($this->attributes, 
      $this->revisions()->orderBy('saved_at', 'desc')->first()->attributesToArray()
    )
  );
}
```

Or use mutators in the model:

```
public function getEditorIdAttribute($value){
  return $this->revisions()->orderBy('saved_at', 'desc')->first()->editor_id;
}
```

Or is there a better way of handling revisions that's more Laravel/Eloquent-like?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: I'm not so sure - after trying a few things I found only one worked for the above case and I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes down this path - I wasn't able to set attributes in the constructor and have them available in the Model so I resorted to using mutators.

To prevent a new query every time a mutator was called (which adds up if you have a handful of mutators) - I used a simple workaround:

```
// Document Model
class Document extends Eloquent{
  $this->latest = ''

  // relations etc here

  public function getSomeValueAttribute{
    $this->getLatest('some_value');
  }

  public function getAnotherValueAttribute{
    $this->getLatest('another_value');
  }

  public function getLatest($attr){
    if(empty($this->latest)) $this->latest = $this->revisions->last();
    return $this->latest->getAttribute($attr);
  }

}
```

I'm sure I can extend the `getValueAttribute()` mutator to keep things DRY, but the above works for me for now, and mutators are called before relations are setup so it works quite well. I'm also able to see all my revisions via `$document->revisions->get()` or just the latest values via `$document->text`.